# Which coach station is easily accessible from Heathrow Airport?

Tags: uk, public-transport, london, buses, lhr

I want to travel from London (Heathrow Airport) to Canterbury.

Can some one tell me which of the following station is easily accessible from Airport? I have seen distances in maps but it can happen that something which is close but has less access, by which I mean public transport.

1. Victoria Coach Station
2. Elephant and Castle
3. Walworth
4. New Cross Gate
5. Lewisham Rail Station
6. Eltham

Any other cheaper ways (around 8 GBP; bus fare is 5GBP) to travel from Heathrow airport to Canterbury is also welcome (though not part of main question).

Comment: Victoria Coach Station is quite a bit of a walk from the tube station -- but Elephant and Castle is also just a single change away from Heathrow by tube. The cash fare is £6, but it gets cheaper if you have an Oyster or contactless card to pay with.

Comment: (E&C will be a curbside bus stop, though -- not a "coach station" as such. So waiting there might be less comfortable).

Comment: You're not going to travel 140km in the UK for less than that! National Express will sell you a coach ticket from Heathrow to Canterbury, with a change at Victoria.

Comment: Easily is relative and quite opinion based. A physically handicapped person for example might find one more easily accessible than the other.

Comment: @user56513 this is the best I can ask. Please feel free to edit to make it better (if you can)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Go to nationalexpress.com/en Enter "LHR T 2/3" as the departure point, and "Canterbury Bus Station" as the destination. Select a date and time. Hit "Find My Journey." The site will display the schedule and prices.

Comment: Looks like there is more than one legitimate answer.  Why are they not actually posted in an answer form instead of a comments form?

Comment: @WGroleau The question is about which coach station is easiest to get to from Heathrow. At the time I posted my comments, it wasn't obvious to me that "Forget about all that and just take the coach from Heathrow" was really an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just ask it to book a ticket from Heathrow to Canterbury. Any terminal will work but it's cheapest and fastest from Terminals 2&3, which is where the main bus station is. If you're arriving at some other terminal, you can get to T2&3 by Underground from T5 or bus from T4, both free.

Go to [nationalexpress.com/en](http://nationalexpress.com/en) Enter "LHR T 2/3" as the departure point, and "Canterbury Bus Station" as the destination. Select a date and time. Hit "Find My Journey." The site will display the schedule and prices.

Comment: This. The simplest road route from LHR to Canterbury is round the southern side of the M25. Travelling into central London to one of the OP's proposed destinations, and then out again, is slow and pointless - unless you want to *spend some time sightseeing* in central London, of course..